# After certain word comes back exit the timing which is to call setInterval()function

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an array the array contains elements I want that elements that contain inside the array to be called inside the setInterval function and when that happens random elements inside the array will start to appear on the console at a specified time if the words inside the array are matched itself call the ClearInterval function.

```
function shuffle(array) {
      let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

          // While there remain elements to shuffle...
            while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
              randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
               currentIndex -= 1;

                // And swap it with the current element.
                   temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
                array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
               array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
              }

                return array;
             }


                     let d = ["d","e","a","d"];


                          let c = setInterval(function(){


                 let r = shuffle(d).join("");

             if(r === "dead"){
                   clearInterval(d)
           }else{
               console.log(shuffle(d).join(""))
            }
           },1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this by changing `clearInterval(c)`

```
function shuffle(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}


let d = ["d", "e", "a", "d"];
let c = setInterval(function() {
    let r = shuffle(d).join("");
    console.log(r)

    if (r === "dead") {
        clearInterval(c) // this should stop here
    } else {
        console.log(shuffle(d).join(""))
    }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: That's what I am talking about thanks mate Allah have mercy on your soul.

Comment: I need your help one more thing can you make it more effective by preventing the coming of the same word .